# Reuse the same AdMob code in other applications

Tags: android, admob

I have created a site/app and am successfully showing ads in one of the applications. Now, I have a second application, where in I want to show the ads (leaving the first application intact, with the ad being displayed). Now, should I create a new site/app in AdMob again. Of course creating a new site/app will show how much I am earning from each app separately. But, in case I don't need that, can I just go a head and copy paste the code (XML Code) in the first app, to the second app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should work but as it's only a matter of replacing a string (the Ad id) while all xml can remain the same. So,  I don't see why you shouldn't take this trouble. Besides as you say it's good to have it separate as you can see how well each one is performing.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no problem reusing the code, but you should be aware that the settings for the application in Admob will be different than your new app (Name/Link etc).

Admob recommends that you create a new site/app for each android application that has advertisements. It will show you how much you earn from each app separately, but there is also a combined view to show the total for both.